# What are the missable achievements in The Dark Eye: Chains of Satinav?

Tags: achievements, the-dark-eye-chains-of-satinav

Which achievements in The Dark Eye: Chains of Satinav can be missed? Are any of them mutually-exclusive? How do I get them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to keep this spoiler-free. Most of this is adapted from [here](http://chainsofsatinavwalkthrough.blogspot.de/2012/06/achievements.html).

### Game-wide achievements

- **Endurance**: Get all achievements
- **A Real Adventurer** / **Hard-boiled Adventurer**:  Complete the game in casual/challenge mode.  Thus, you must complete the game twice to get all of the achievements.
- **Eagle-eye**: Use the hotspot indicator no more than 50 times throughout the game.
- **Destroyer** / **Healer**: Break/fix 100 items.  Breaking/fixing the same item repeatedly counts.

## Chapter 1

- **Penny Pincher**: Win a prize from Hilda by spending no more than two kreutzer *[(How?)](http://chainsofsatinavwalkthrough.blogspot.com/2012/06/theoakleafchallenge.html#pennypincher)*
- **Humble Servant** / **Loud-mouthed Bragger**:  When speaking to the king, either be formal+humble or proud+brag.  You must save beforehand if you want to get both.
- **Fisherman** / **Thruster**: Collect the magic water with/without smashing the fairy gate *[(How?)](http://chainsofsatinavwalkthrough.blogspot.com/2012/06/tocatchafairy.html#thruster)*.  You must save beforehand if you want to get both.
- **Mack the Knife**: Try to stab other characters with the knife 10 times *(this can also be done in chapter 2)*

## Chapter 2

- **Horse-whisperer**: Talk to the horse 10 times
- **A romantic heart**: Offer Nuri either the blanket or the oneberry flowers
- **Snoop**: Ask Nuri to eavesdrop on the orks four times
- **Marksman**: Get the directions to Nuri on your first try by..

  > ..throwing the paper into the wicker basket
- **Light Board Operator**: Ask Nuri to move the light in the ceiling 50 times

## Chapter 3

- **Ladies Man** / **Not a Ladies Man** / **An honest man**: At the camp site, Accept Nuri / Reject Nuri / Tell Nuri the truth.  You'll need to save and reload if you want all three.

## Chapter 4

- **Feelin' Dizzy**: In the art gallery, flip the painting of the gardens 20 times.
- **Changing seasons**: In the art gallery, place and remove the color stone from the bottom basin 5 times.
- **World-whisperer**: Find the hidden pantaloons *[(Where?)](http://chainsofsatinavwalkthrough.blogspot.com/2012/06/thedreamchambers.html#worldwhisperer)*

## Chapter 5

- **Philanthropist** / **He Died for the Cause**:  To get these you must enter the academy...

  > ...having saved/not saved Olgierd *[(How?)](http://chainsofsatinavwalkthrough.blogspot.com/2012/06/academyofmagic.html)*

  You have to save beforehand if you want to get both in one playthrough!
- **Book Worm**: Look at every book in the library *(including the ones on Raven's Peak, which you'll get the option to read later)*

All the rest you will get simply by playing through the game.